# How to search zipcode using uszipcode by specifying latitude and longitude of an unique zipcode type?

Tags: python-3.6

I am using uszipcode lib in python3 to find out zipcodes based on latitude and longitude. I searched for the particular value it is not displaying the particular zipcode however this zipcode does exist. my code is below

```
from uszipcode import Zipcode
from uszipcode import SearchEngine
search = SearchEngine(simple_zipcode=True)
result = search.by_coordinates(39.0300,-77.5000,radius=30,returns=100)
result
```

Results

```
[SimpleZipcode(zipcode='20147', zipcode_type='Standard', major_city='Ashburn', 
post_office_city='Ashburn, VA', common_city_list=['Ashburn'], county='Loudoun County', 
state='VA', lat=39.05, lng=-77.48, timezone='Eastern', radius_in_miles=5.0, 
area_code_list=['703'], population=54086, population_density=2721.0, 
land_area_in_sqmi=19.87, water_area_in_sqmi=0.32, 
housing_units=19719, occupied_housing_units=19046, 
median_home_value=444000, median_household_income=122115,
bounds_west=-77.530888, bounds_east=-77.431157, 
bounds_north=39.085911, bounds_south=38.993544), ....
```

It doesn't return zipcode 20149. Is any thing I missed for here? Please suggest.. Thanks in advance

```
from uszipcode import Zipcode
from uszipcode import SearchEngine
search = SearchEngine(simple_zipcode=True)
result = search.by_coordinates(39.0300,-77.5000,radius=30,returns=100)
result
```

Comment: What basis do you have for assuming it should return 20149?

Comment: Thank you Scott.. If I search 10 miles from zipcode 20147. It is less than 10 miles from zipcode 20149. This is why I am thinking it should come as result.

Comment: But it may not be 10 miles from the location in 20147 you are using.

Comment: https://www.zip-codes.com/distance_calculator.asp?zip1=20148&zip2=20149&submit=Calculate

it is less than 10 miles